# Box combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

Given 2023 boxes and each them has an number of coins (it can be 0 coin). Each turn, pick a box with at least 2 coins and take 2 coins from it, 1 coin is put in another box and 1 is thrown away. A set of 2023 boxes is called “cool” if after presenting an finite set of turns, every boxes have at least 1 coin. A set of 2023 boxes is called “almost cool” if when you add 1 coin to 1 of 2023 boxes, this set change to “cool”. Know that two sets of boxes are distinguished if there is at least 1 box in these sets has different coins. Find the number of sets of boxes that are “almost cool”.

—————————————-

This problem hurts my brain so much for how complicated my attempts are. I would first have

Thought 1(intuitive): move coin between two boxes is useless for the progress of making 2023 boxes all have coin.

Thought 2: If we called S the number of total coins in the set of boxes so that this set is “almost cool”. Then 2022<=S<=4044.
I know this because it can be proved that every set of boxes with more than 4044 coins are “cool”, while any sets less than 2023 can not be “cool”.

Thought 3: Ai is the numbers of boxes that do not have any coins in turn i, if we called Bi the total numbers of times all the other boxes can get coin from without turning these boxes into 0 coin in turn i (for example, if a box have 3 coins then we can get 1 time, 2 or 1 coin then we can get none) then Bi>=Ai for every i until Ai=0

These are all my thoughts but I could not go any further because of the complexity of the remaining of the solve. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What if you happen to pick a box which is empty or has one coin? Then you cannot take 2 coins from that box, put one in another box and throw the other away. [maybe you just pick another box which has at least 2 coins.] A more important issue is that if as it seems the choices made are somehow random, then it cannot really be determined if a configuration is "cool"; i.e. it's random whether after finite number of turns each box is nonempty.

Comment: @coffeemath I would say that you need to choose the box with at least 2 coins. And the choices are made in order to make every boxes have coins, so it is not random but intentionally.

Comment: You should re-write the question part. Something like: On a turn, one may pick one of the 2023 boxes having 2 or more coins in it, throw one coin away and place one coin in some other box of one's choice. A configuration is called "cool" provided it is possible to perform a finite number of turns so that afterward each of the 2023 boxes is nonempty.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig this is from a mock exam preparing for national olympiad in my country.

Answer (score 2):

Credit for this solution goes to Minhao Bai, who solved the problem on the blackboard as soon as I told it to him. Any mistakes or unclear explanations here have probably been introduced by me as I try to remember it.

An important assumption I'll make in my answer is that the boxes are *labeled*, so the setup where "box 1 has 1 coin and box 2 has 0 coins" and that where "box 1 has 0 coins and box 2 has 1 coin" are *different*. You can also ask the question for the setup where the boxes are unlabeled.

If I want to talk about a setup with boxes 1, 2, and 3, where box1 has 2 coins, box2 has 3 coins, and box3 has 0 coins, I will write this as $(2,3,0)$. In general, a set of boxes with coins in them can be identified with a point $x \in \mathbb{N}^n,$ where $n$ is the number of boxes and $x_m$ is the number of coins in box $m$.

Let $\mathcal{A}_n \subset \mathbb{N}^n$ be the set of almost cool configurations of coins in $n$ boxes. If $n \geq 2$ and $x \in \mathcal{A},$
then the set of $0$-indexes in $x,$
$$K=K(x):=\{j \in \{1,2,...,n\} : x_j = 0\}$$
has size
$$1 \leq \#K \leq n-1.$$
The number of "free pairs" of coins in $x,$
$$M = M(x):=\sum_{i \in \{1,2,...,n\} \setminus K} \left\lfloor \frac{x_i-1}{2} \right\rfloor$$
is the number of "moves" we could do. (A "move" is the thing where we take two coins away from a box with at least 3 coins, throw away one, and add one to an empty box. You can check that we never need to do any other type of move. (We never need to add coins to a non-empty box, and we never take coins away from a box with fewer than 3 coins.))

A key observation is that, since $x$ is almost cool, $M = \#K-1.$ That is, there are exactly $k-1$ "free pairs" of coins in the endowed boxes. That way, we can give something to all but one of the initially-empty boxes.

When doing "moves" to get from our starting position to our final position, we never remove the last two coins (or the last one coin) from a box. Among the $n-\#K$ filled boxes, some have an odd number of coins (they'll have one coin left once their free pairs are removed), and some have an even number of coins (they'll have two coins left once free pairs are removed).

So, to *form* an almost cool distribution of coins in boxes, we first choose a set of boxes to be empty (if $k$ boxes are to be empty, there are ${n \choose k}$ ways to choose them); then, among the nonempty boxes, we choose some to have an even number of coins, and some odd (there are $2^{n-k}$ ways to pick the set of odd nonempty boxes); then finally, we can add our $k-1$ "free pairs" ("pair" meaning two coins at a time, for a total of $2k-2$ coins) to the $n-k$ nonempty boxes, in any way we please (there are ${n-2 \choose k-1}$ ways to do this, by a "stars and bars" argument). Every element of $\mathcal{A}_n$ (every almost cool distribution) can be found by this process in exactly one way, and everthing gotten by this process is almost cool. Therefore, for $n \geq 2,$
$$\# \mathcal{A}_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n \choose k} {n-2 \choose k-1} 2^{n-k}.$$

Here are the first few values of $a_n = \# \mathcal{A}_n$, starting with $a_1$:

$$1, 4, 18, 88, 450, 2364, 12642, ...$$

These data suggest that $a_n$ is given by sequence A050146 in the OEIS, but I have not proven this [edit: confirmed]. In any case, the above sum can be directly computed for $n = 2023.$ The answer to the original question (written out in base 10) is:

$15862712306907673148566364602873435012268070255341425082263502105847785568$$22199154331336246694599699785377223845049008448798497219503346888190255839$$62864144173430566794017053203992025434012762001321941581413875699216427884$$64081106219215412521195684723945974286375946410392836468203406997944816985$$28072763507602764085246662049167687391086951006986599636476349197477303182$$22382335167332410910042097921172175972750657433577905386380900958227132576$$02957210968141300653301769293046005992203336231643672423445705995623182161$$22556667533652598084032699752158175645548163903423880948767845464608506059$$99428354736970641863116433255527643871508057595837250337724071109104788851$$96738816034798129328806998027935515105511260512565439602250140473228661544$$67865039034242853265453881363680021267632719869701179304662638824905394154$$38256930895936994707421734397357799074646843826829702879303567055021607028$$55874990047380296428742054329930148000233606474861203272672619830789875271$$26052939004783276514569468282839656395894126829900775973025121314539406372$$42047958922493684187101829824976380973137072683829787331555988483320622138$$08414740620496678147406934984152653314477757754467261847882287386998593269$$79975076569281073689796217667557006652824355618116915460901471028799469049$$93675660760394261747843264798948977849759630244410724840750660649267931092$$68411914801519192774375762175952725492097951905417601900860080898877601263$$64423784540051413200631239288253053995247546282815098491895129490776199398$$9333707430917263152520090216775210693060046003076147908610858194402.$

This is about $1.586 \times 10^{1546}$

Edit: with the help of Robert Dougherty-Bliss using the Zeilberger algorithm, I have confirmed that the above sequence is given by A050146.

Comment: I enjoy posting long numbers in my answers, but that must be the longest number I've ever seen posted here :-)